# Bash Shell Prompt change color when in root mode

Tags: terminal, mojave, bash

Mac OS X, how do I set the bash shell prompt (PS1) that every time the user type `sudo su` (root mode) the shell prompt change from the standard color to the red color and of course if the user exit from the root mode the color revert back to the default color.  Basically what I am trying to do, is to warning the user that he/she is in root mode, so be careful.

I know I can put the following line `PS1="\e[0;31m[\u@\h \W]\$ \e[m "` inside the user personal `.bash_profile` but I guess this is not the correct approach.

Comment: So far I only vim .bash_profile and I added the following line: PS1="\e[0;31m[\u@\h \W]\$ \e[m " but once again it does not help.  I want to be red only if the user is within the root.  Example if I type sudo su after I authenticate my password, I want the following sh-3.2# to be red color

Comment: *Much* more important is that you stop doing things like 'sudo su', especially since you think it's something called "root mode", which it is not.

Comment: Thanks Marc.  So what is the exact mode I should call when I am in this mode: sh-3.2#

Answer (score -1):

One approach is to define your prompt in your .bashrc-

```
#sudo -s in .bashrc
case $LOGNAME in
root) PS1="\e[0;31m[\u@\h \W]\$ \e[m "
      ;;
   *) PS1="\h:\W \u\$ "
      ;;
esac
```

and place the following in your .bash_profile-

```
case $- in
        *i*) . ~/.bashrc ;;
esac
```

This will source .bashrc if your shell is a login interactive shell, otherwise .bashrc is read if your shell is a non-login interactive shell. Users are encouraged to use `sudo -s` instead of `sudo su`.

The advantage is that the invoking user keeps their environment and shell with `sudo -s`.

Comment: fd0 my apologies.  I guess i did not express myself correctly.  Basically every time the user type (sudo su) on their mac os x system I want the prompt to be changed to red color.

Comment: @Fabio Viola- Well, at first I missed the su in sudo but was offering another approach. `sudo su` will produce a non-login interactive shell. The manual states that `sh` reads `/etc/profile` and `~/.profile` when invoked as a login shell then `ENV` if set and a non-login interactive shell would read the file assigned to the `ENV `variable. `ENV` and `~/.profile` can also be read by `zsh` and `ksh` so you need to shield these files from `bashism`.

Comment: @fd0 And who's bash_profile and bashrc will it be reading?